# how to count values in php array and while loop

Tags: php

I'm using MySQL query `"SELECT * FROM ..."`

And a `while` loop:

```
$rtnjsonobj = array();  
while ($k = @mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) { 
   $rtnjsonobj['status'] = $k['status'];
   $rtnjsonobj['text'] = $k['text'];
   $data[] = $rtnjsonobj;  
}
```

I need to count all the values in this array ​​that have `status == 1`.
How can I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql` extension, but `mysqli` instead. `mysql` is deprecated by PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
$rtnjsonobj = array();  
while ($k = @mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) { 
$rtnjsonobj['status'] = $k['status'];
$rtnjsonobj['text'] = $k['text'];
$data[] = $rtnjsonobj;  
if($k['status'] == 1)
   $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

this will save a second query to the databse

Comment: Simple and effective :)

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop.  Please explore the SQL Language further.

```
Select  Count(*)
From    TableName
Where   Status = 1
```

Edit:

If you have your heart set on counting it in PHP, simply create a counter set to 0 and increment when the value is found.

```
$Count = 0;
$rtnjsonobj = array();  
while ($k = @mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) { 
   $rtnjsonobj['status'] = $k['status'];
   $rtnjsonobj['text'] = $k['text'];
   if($k['status'] == 1)
       $Count++;
   $data[] = $rtnjsonobj;  
}
```

Comment: @Cheruvian: I can not use "WHERE status = 1" because I need other values in the result where status != 1

Answer (score 0):

In your select you can imbricate another query as such :

```
Select *, (select count(*) from mytable where status=1) as myCounter from ...
```

Or increment a variable in your `while` loop :

```
$rtnjsonobj = array();
$myCounter = 0;
while ($k = @mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) { 
   $rtnjsonobj['status'] = $k['status'];
   $rtnjsonobj['text'] = $k['text'];
   $data[] = $rtnjsonobj;
   if($k['status'] == 1){$myCounter++;}
}
echo $myCounter;
```

Comment: This will replicate the count to every row though. Generally frowned upon in DB queries

Answer (score 0):

Use array_reduce:

> array_reduce — Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function

```
function mycount($carry, $item) {
    $carry += $item['status'] == 1 ? 1 : 0;
    return $carry;
}

$num = array_reduce($rtnjsonobj, "mycount");
```

By the way you should do the count from SQL.